# There is 4unique color in column G3:G. I need a formula to count the unique value of G3:G and show it in P3:P. If B;B is blank then it will blank

Tags: google-sheets

[enter link description here](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1gGzp4cuaFDcc-goPf_fAHPQMBf1Uz6MaenPQonLlqLo/edit#gid=0)I have used `=if(b3:b="","",sumif(SUMIF(H3:H,H3:H,Q3:Q)))` in S3:S. Now I want to use a formula in column P3:P that will count unique value of column G3:G. I have tried `=IF(B3="","",COUNTA(UNIQUE(G3:G)))` But it's showing wrong output.

[image]

Comment: Your sheet is private.

Answer (score 0):

```
=COUNTA(QUERY(B:G, "SELECT G WHERE B is NULL"))
```

`QUERY` function will return all cells from column G where A is blank.
`COUNTA` will count all of the values returned by `QUERY`.

Let me know if that is what you need.

Comment: No this is not what I want. I want the formula to count the unique value of column G3:G, when b3:b is not blank.

Answer (score 0):

You need `Group By` clause to query function. Try-

```
=QUERY(B3:G,"select G, count(G) where B is not null group by G label count(G) ''")
```

Comment: sorry it also fails to bring my desire outcome

Comment: @shanto Then we couldn't understand your question. Can you make little more explanation to make it clear.

Comment: See under 22FW in B3 there are 4 unique color in column G:G. I want to show this(4) in column P3 as b3 is not blank. same like column S3 & S15 where it shows the sum of column Q;Q under the condition of b<>"".

Answer (score 0):

maybe:

```
=IF(B3<>"", COUNTA(UNIQUE(G$3:G)))
```

(share a copy / sample of your sheet with an example of the desired output)

Comment: it works but partially. its show the total unique names (5)of column G:G. but see before 23SS in B15 there are 4 unique color name. my desire outcome is like column S.